# Xcode Build Phases: Headers vs Copy Files

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, build-settings

What's the difference between these Xcode Build Phases: Headers & Copy Files?

When I add a Cocoa Touch Static Library (iOS) to my project, it comes with a Copy Files build phase, whereas when I add a Plain Static Library (macOS), it comes with a Headers build phase.

The source code of the target I'm adding is written entirely in C. And, I want to be able to include this project in my other projects that contain iOS & macOS application targets.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is very simple in fact (applicable for static libraries, but *not* frameworks):

- **Headers Phase** copies all *Public* and *Private* headers into `/usr/local/include` folder, so they are available system-wide on macOS when installing the library (while developing, Xcode just creates this folder hierarchy under `$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)` for you, so you can inspect the headers as needed).
- **Copy Files** offers product-specific destination `$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/include/$(PRODUCT_NAME)`, where headers are supposed to be delivered alongside the library binary.

The second approach is more flexible (while you can use the **Copy Files** phase in both macOS and iOS, using **Headers Phase** makes sense in macOS only).

P.S. Be advised that for *frameworks* the **Headers Phase** works differently and in fact embed the headers with the framework being developed, so in this case it's a more preferred way.